# jQgrid "loadComplete" event is not being called ONLY on first load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

My problem is the following, I have a jQgrid being loaded when a button is pressed. When the grid loads for the first time it does not call the `loadComplete` function, which in this case would call `modifEmitidoRecibidoPorEstado()`.

What the grid is doing right now is loading normally but it does not show any records, this doesn't mean it is empty, it just does not display the records.

Then, when I either manually change the amount of records being shown (in the grid pager) or change the grid page, the grid reloads showing the records it should show, and calls the `loadComplete` event. The grid also loads correctly when I execute `$('#listaCheques').trigger('reloadGrid');`, the problem is I can only do this manually (by pressing a button for example), since I first must wait for the grid to finish loading.

What I need is the grid to correctly load on the first time, this includes calling the `loadComplete` event.

The fact that it takes about 2 to 10 seconds for the grid to finish loading may be important, it has to wait for all the data to be received.

Grid creation and load function:

```
   //first time the function is called first == true
   if (first==false){
        jQuery('#listaCheques').jqGrid('clearGridData');
        $("#listaCheques").jqGrid('setPostData',datosConsulta); 
        $("#listaCheques").trigger("reloadGrid");
    }else{
        first=false;
        $("#listaCheques").GridUnload();
        jQuery("#listaCheques").jqGrid({
                loadError:  checkErrors,
                mtype : 'POST',
                url:path+'/something.do?reqCode=load',
                datatype: 'json',
                postData:datosConsulta,
                colNames:[//not relevant],
                colModel:[//not relevant],
               beforeSelectRow: function(rowid, e) {//remove yellow highlight
                    return false;
                },
               rowNum: JQGRID_PARAMETERS.rowNum,
               rowList: JQGRID_PARAMETERS.rowList,
               pager: '#pagerCheques',
               sortname: 'chequeNumero',
               viewrecords: true,
               emptyrecords:'message',
               sortorder: "asc",
               loadComplete:modifEmitidoRecibidoPorEstado,
               gridComplete:gridFixIExplorer,
               jsonReader : {
                    root: "response.rows",
                    page: "response.page",
                    total: "response.total",
                    records: "response.records",
                    repeatitems: false
                },     
                width:'100%',
                height: '100%'
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of jqGrid is used? It seems to be a very old.

The expression **$("#listaCheques").GridUnload();** means that jqGrid is already created and I'm not sure that it is correct calling of it.

I recommend you to remove this line of code and test.

Comment: You are right, I know that code is useless but since this is a very old and big banking system I would rather leave it as it is now, however I tested removing it and the issue stays the same. The jqgrid version in use is 3.8.1. I contacted my temmates about this error and it seems like it is only ocurring locally on my computer.